# Remove Reference using Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a macro file (`.dotm` file) which gets changed from time to time.

However, if someone used a macro from a different file, it creates a reference to the `.dotm` file in the References folder for the project.  Can I have some script that checks that folder and if that file is now missing/broken to remove that Reference?

Answer (score 1):

@user1243498 : Following code will remove the broken references

```
 Sub referencecheck()

 Dim ref As Reference

 Dim yourproject As VBProject

 Set yourproject = ActiveDocument.VBProject

 For Each ref In yourproject.References

 If ref.IsBroken Then

 yourproject.References.Remove (ref)

 End If

 End Sub
```

for better understanding please refer the following site

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308340