Microsoft Word VBA Normal.dotm References
This may not be a part of the problem, but every time I open a new Word document, I receive a pop up saying "Sorry, we couldn't find your file. Was it moved, renamed, or deleted?". The only option is "OK".
I think this might be because under the Developer tab, under "Visual Basic", the Normal Project has a reference to a document I have deleted.
I am unable to delete the document under References.
I am not sure if I need to open up the "Syneos_CaMe_RB.docm" file.
I am wanting to not have a document under references.
This is what it looks like currently:


See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335006/remove-reference-using-word-vba/20233811#20233811 and https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-check-and-remove-incorrect-project-references-in-the-visual-basic-editor-in-word-7ba187a6-9dfd-1288-8f08-d1f01ea02a3f

you can remove the .docm file and save a new template, then each time you open a new word document you wont have to deal with the pop-up. I could be wrong, but my guess is this is a poor key registry attempt.

if it doesnt matter, you can also just silence the alerts

DisplayAlerts = False:  but youll probably fix the true issue going down that pathway regardless

In the vba project Normal, delete the reference to the missing document.
